# Allure Report To Contain Multiple Test Projects

Tags: allure

I'm looking to user Allure to report for my multiple test suites, what I would like to know is am I able to have multiple test projects under one allure instance.

My project is currently made up of:

- 2 UI projects
- 2 API projects

I currently have UI tests (cypress.io) for both projects and I'm working on building out the test framework for both API projects.

Can I organise allure so that I can navigate to one instance for all 4 test frameworks or will I have to have an allure instance for each of the test frameworks (resulting in 4 allure homepages).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Allure Docker Service, now provides support for multiple projects:
https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service#MULTIPLE-PROJECTS---REMOTE-REPORTS

Comment: Thanks. We've since gone with a different system architecture that now negates this issue. But this is still good to know.